# Import datetime and convert to minutes on plot

Tags: matlab

I have recorded data for 24h with frequency 4hz, so I have 4 values per second. The following time stamp in example is: 17:23:21:000 (HH:mm:ss:SSS). I want to import time data in matlab so, that in plot on x axis it shows  as minutes not this long times stamp example. Can someone explain me how? Thank you!

Comment: You should tag your post with relevant tags to help people find it.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`datetick`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html) to make your axis show formatted datetimes:

```
datetick(gca,'HH:mm')
```